# Transfer file to Windows server from Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, rsync, transfer

I am transferring file to Windows server from Ubuntu with following command:

```
smbclient //server_ip_add/share -U username
```

We can use `rsync` to transfer file from Ubuntu to Ubuntu and then by creating script run it as cronjob. Is it possible to do all this from Ubuntu to Windows?

Comment: You could mount the samba share on Ubuntu, then there is absolutely no difference on what OS the server is running.

Comment: sorry i don't have thoroughly knowledge of all this.  will you please tell me what does it mean- mounting samba share?

Comment: Mounting the samba share (the smb share)  in your Ubuntu system, means that ubuntu will see the share as just another location seamlessly integrated in its filesystem. (it will just seam to be another folder). You could then run rsync just as usual.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently here you can find a detailed howto. Use cifs not smbfs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I used [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) method to transfer file via **rsync** automatically.

First I mount a windows share folder (or map network drive) to which i want to transfer file with following method:

```
sudo mkdir /media/BACKUP
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=domainusername //ip_add/ShareFolder /media/BACKUP
```

then use rsync to transfer file:

```
sudo rsync -azp /path/to/source /media/BACKUP/ShareFolder
```

Create script,make it executable and schedule a cronjob.

Now if you reboot the system, it will be unmounted. So to mount it permanently, do following:

Open terminal & run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

**Edit:**

```
//ip_add/ShareFolder /media/BACKUP/ cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Here `.smbcredentials` is a credential file created in home directory

To create it, run `gedit ~/.smbcredentials`

**Edit:**

```
username=domainusername
password=Password
```

save & close it.

**UPDATE: For Ubuntu 16.04.3, and 18.04, edit `vers=1.0`**

```
//ip_add/ShareFolder /media/BACKUP/ cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for Windows that implements `rsync`. It is called [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.net/content/cwrsync-free-edition) and is published by [itefix](https://www.itefix.net).

It has packaged `rsync` and `cygwin` with the sole purpose to give a simple solution to install `rsync` on windows.

This [link](https://www.gefoo.org/rsync-your-backup-files-from-a-linux-box-to-a-windows-box.html) gives a step-by-step description of how to set it up and how to use it.

Obviously, [itefix](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync) publish their own documentation.

I've used it successfully to copy 2GB+ of attachments over from a Ubuntu server to an IIS7 server. The attachments were part of a database application.