# Copying files from Ubuntu to Windows share via command line

Tags: command-line, windows

I want to copy from an Ubuntu directory to a Windows share. It's easy if I use the GUI, but I want to use a command in the terminal instead. I've tried this

```
cp -u -r /home/mirror-dlp/ /smb://computername/file.share/
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can also use `rsync`. Please check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu-with-rsync/678188#678188) post.