# How to mount a samba share at login

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, cron

I need to mount a smb share in my laptop. I added it in fstab, but it doesn't seem to be mounting at boot. I need to type `mount -a` manually to mount it. I think it is because the laptop is not getting connected to the network when its booted. I tried to add a cron to mount it 1 minute after reboot, but it is also not working.

Since I am the only one using this laptop, it is Ok to mount it when I login. So how to add a cronjob to mount it when I login ?

OS: ubuntu 16.04

samba running in a raspberry pi in home network

Comment: Can you post the relevant line in your fstab? My setup mounts samba shares every boot with no trouble.

Comment: @OrganicMarble `//192.168.1.200/movies /movies cifs username=root,password=xxxx 0 0 `

Comment: Try adding `,nobootwait` after your `,password=xxxx` entry.  My fstab entries also have `,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[me],gid=[me],` but I don't know if that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: adding `nobootwait` did not solve the problem. let me try with all these entries

Comment: Your tag says you have 14.04 but your question says 16.04.  It's important because 16.04 doesn't support `nobootwait`.  If you really have 16.04, try `nofail` instead.

Comment: none of them worked

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas :(

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu-using-rsync/678188#678188).

Answer (score 1):

Add the command to mount the share at the end of `~/.bash_profile`. This will execute the command when you login.

Answer (score 0):

To mount samba share automatically when system reboot, You need to add an entry to the `/etc/fstab` file.

```
//server-name/sharename /mountpoint cifs username=smbuser,password=smbpass 0 0
```

When system reboot, Ubuntu will mount the samba share specified in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: I have done this but the drive does not mount. I think it may have to do with network services being unavailable when it attempts to mount.

Comment: Did you install "cifs-utils"?