# Trouble mounting a Windows 7 share on Ubuntu Server 16.04 with no password using cifs

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, permissions, cifs

I am trying to mount a Windows 7 share on Ubuntu Server 16.04 with no password using cifs.

```
sudo mount.cifs //win/share /media/win -o username=,passsword=,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I get a permission denied error:

```
sudo mount.cifs //win/share /media/win -o username=win/user,passsword=,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Also gives me a permission denied error.

In Windows 7, I have given permission to "Everyone" and have given share access to "Everyone". Both have full control.

If I try `username=guest`, I get a `mount error 127 - key has expired`. And if I exclude the `password=`, `mount` asks for a password and I again get `mount error 13 - permission denied`. I have also tried adding `iocharset=uft8` and `uid=1000` but that does not have an effect.

If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Please check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu-with-rsync/678188#678188) post.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that post doesn't deal with mounting shares without a password.

Comment: Since I wasn't able to make it work with an account with no password, I ended up making an account with a password and it connected with no issue.

Comment: So you just want to mount it only once.. Not every time..