# Nautilus not showing mounted drives in side bar

Tags: nautilus, 18.04

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Files/Nautilus: 3.26.3
GNOME: GNOME Shell 3.28.1

Nautilus not showing mounted drives and Computer(/) in the side bar, but are visible in "Other Locations"
Is there some config file I can change or some settings I'm missing to achieve the aforementioned.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 27):

You need to bookmark them and will likely want to rename the bookmark. This GIF illustrates the technique:

[image: Nautilus 18 bookmark.gif]

1. Pick a partition from your "Other Locations" list.
2. Click the upper right "hamburger"  (☰) menu.
3. From the dropdown menu click the center menu button to bookmark it.
4. Move to the new sidebar entry and rename it from the mount name ("c" in my example) to something more meaningful ("Windows 10 SSD" in my example).

Comment: Though works, I wanted the buttons like the OtherLocation buttons, which mounts the drive when not mounted and also has the option of unmounting on right side.

Comment: This happened automatically before Ubuntu 18.04. Does know of a setting to return to the old behavior, where mounted ISO files and devices popped up in the sidebar?

Comment: @feeela I will keep using 16.04 until 18.04 is better. Not just for Nautilus but in most departments overall. Nautilus is made by the folks at **Gnome** not by **Ubuntu** so you could try requesting the feature from them.

Comment: OK, understood. But strangely enough, this already was a feature…

Comment: @feeela Many people share your frustration how good features disappear after upgrades. Did you try the answer below posted by DAISY?

Comment: Sems [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1533) ([fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/merge_requests/722)) upstream issue.

Comment: No. It's ugly because the bookmark is only a soft link instead of a pending udisks device which can be mounted via mouse click.

Comment: @funicorn Who were you directing your comment at?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Bookmarking a mouted device is NOT even a workaround, because it's invalid after the device's been unmounted. What makes it worse is one cannot mount the device again by clicking on that bookmark. I's ugly in that it distorts rather than fixes the `click->mount->open` user interface, which should be provided in `Nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

Issue is resolved once I added entry into `/etc/fstab`.

I've followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677773/transfer-file-to-windows-server-from-ubuntu-using-rsync/678188#678188) same method to mount

```
sudo mkdir /media/BACKUP
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=domainusername //ip_add/ShareFolder /media/BACKUP
```

and added entry into `/etc/fstab`.

```
//ip_add/ShareFolder /media/BACKUP/ cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm 0 0
```